# How to find out the number of arguments (using variable arguments) if the first argument just indicates and enum value?

Tags: c

So I am given an list of enum values. This function will return integer value. It takes in an enum value and the rest is followed by integer values. I am supposed to get the total of the following integer values if the enum type is called total and return the total.

Comment: Is your function like `int func(enum Kind k, ...)` ? and Call like `int sum = func(Total, 1,2,3);`

Comment: it's like int fund (Rule rule, int one,...)

Comment: the second arg given doesn't indicate the number of the integer arguments that follows so I don't know how to get the total

Comment: In such a case `one` must be the number of remaining arguments.

Comment: it's not the case. That's why I am confused

Comment: Well also the arguments always ends with a -1

Comment: so  i need to find a way to check if it has reached -1

Comment: @HiruSepalika Please add these details to the question itself.

Comment: If valid data does not include `-1` then you can know the end of the element.

Comment: so an example of the function call would be func(Rule rule, 7,5,3,1 -1)  and -1 would always indicate the end of the arguments which means the total would not include -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

typedef enum rule {
    first, total
} Rule;

int fund(Rule rule, int v1, ...){
    switch(rule){
    case total:
        {
            int total = v1, value;
            if(v1 == -1) return 0;
            va_list ap;

            va_start(ap, v1);
            value = va_arg(ap, int);
            while(value != -1){
                total += value;
                value = va_arg(ap, int);
            }
            va_end(ap);

            return total;
        }
        break;
    case first:
        return v1;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(void){
    printf("first:%d\n", fund(first, 1, 2, 3, 4, -1));//first:1
    printf("total:%d\n", fund(total, 7, 5, 3, 1, -1));//total:16
}
```

Comment: [DEMO](http://ideone.com/phcXO9)

Comment: I am not getting the right value for the total. If I use rule as my second arg for va_start I get the following error.. " second parameter of 'va_start' not last named argument"

Comment: @HiruSepalika Show me your code. The second argument is not specified in the prototype. What is the purpose of argument `one`?

Comment: if(rule == first)
        return v1;
    else if(rule == total) {
        va_list ap;
        va_start(ap, v1);
        int total = 0;
        int number = 0;
        number = va_arg(ap, int);
        while(number != -1){
            total += number;
            number = va_arg(ap, int);
        }
        va_end(ap);
        return total;
    }
      return 0;}

Comment: @HiruSepalika Is `v1` included in total in this case?

Comment: yes it should be included

Comment: @HiruSepalika You can `return total + v1;` instead of `return total;`

Comment: Thanks that worked!

Comment: But this wont work if v1 is -1

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya sure. I will fix.

Comment: I can just add that condition before actually calculating the total

Comment: Do you guys know how to get the element right before it finds -1

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Do you know how to get the element right before -1

Comment: @HiruSepalika It is only that the validity of an element is other than `-1`. So If programmers passed `-1,1,2,3,-1`, The program returns 0 even if it is not intended by the programmer.

Comment: I am confused. I just want to return the element right before the last element which is always -1

Comment: @BLUEPIXY ? How would you do that

Comment: @HiruSepalika I don't get you. Please explain exactly what kind of situation you are assuming.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that the end of your arguments is marked by a `-1`. This means you can keep getting more arguments until you get a `-1`.

Following is the way you can do it using `va_list` -

```
if(rule == TYPE) {
    int total = 0;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, rule);
    int j;
    while(1){
        j = va_arg(args, int);
        if(j!=-1)
            total += j;
        else
            break;
    }
    va_end(args);
    return total;
}
```

You mentioned in the comments that your prototype is

```
int choose(Rule rule, int v1, ...);
```

In that case you need the modifications -

At the very top

```
if(v1 == -1)
    return 0;
```

And

```
int total = v1;
va_list args;
va_start(args, v1);
```

Demo [Here](https://ideone.com/rWdgtb)

Comment: va_start(args, rule) is giving me an error. When I used my second argument it worked. Also I am getting wrong numbers

Comment: Second argument? You said there is only 1 fixed argument. How did you give the second argument?

Comment: Can you show your prototype?

Comment: int choose( Rule rule, int v1, ... )

Comment: Why is v1 there? cant you make `int choose (Rule rule, ...);`

Comment: Check the edits I suggested.

Comment: This is wat i have to work off of